# Why is rabbitmq keep logging unknown delivery tag 'basic.ack'?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ keep logging

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Aug-2014::06:25:07 ===
connection <0.109.6880>, channel 1 - soft error:
{amqp_error,precondition_failed,"unknown delivery tag 1",'basic.ack'}
```

the log file is quite large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are acking wrong delivery tag which is already was ack-ed or never exists in terms of current channel. See you application source code to figure out how it happens.

Comment: Adding to the answer, a common problem is the application accessing the channel from a different thread.

Comment: Its Due to ack error,sending wrong acknowledge then this error occur.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my consumer had `autoAck` enabled and was also manually acknowledging the message after processing.  The manual acknowledgment threw the same error you're encountering.

Once I removed the manual acknowledgment, I did not see the error again.

To add to @pinepain 's answer, double acknowledgements throw an exception and close the channel per these relavant [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html):

```
When manual acknowledgements are used, it is important to consider what thread does the acknowledgement. If it's different from the thread that received the delivery (e.g. Consumer#handleDelivery delegated delivery handling to a different thread), acknowledging with the multiple parameter set to true is unsafe and will result in double-acknowledgements, and therefore a channel-level protocol exception that closes the channel. Acknowledging a single message at a time can be safe.
```